# Python not letting me print ASCII

Tags: python

Every time I try to print ASCII with the print statement it does not work for some reason

```
print("""
██╗░░██╗███████╗██╗░░░░░██╗░░░░░░█████╗░
██║░░██║██╔════╝██║░░░░░██║░░░░░██╔══██╗
███████║█████╗░░██║░░░░░██║░░░░░██║░░██║
██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██║░░░░░██║░░░░░██║░░██║
██║░░██║███████╗███████╗███████╗╚█████╔╝
╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝╚══════╝░╚════╝░
""")
```

And instead of printing it it just shows an error

```
print("""
  File "C:\Users\Gakhuna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", 
line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-41: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Does your python script have the the correct encoding?